# AngularJS wrong reference in $destroy function while destruction of the scope in ngRepeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

- Please add few items. They will have ids like 1, 2, 3.
- Then please remove one before last item.
- id: 2 should be referred in scope $destroy function, but last is
  always referred.

Am I doing something wrong or is it AngularJS bug?
Can I somehow workaround it?

```js
/*
  bug description:
  click add button add two items,
  then remove first item
  (wrong scope is refered in scope $on destroy function)
*/

var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.values = [];
  
  $scope.add = () => { $scope.values.push(''); };
  $scope.remove = ($index) => { $scope.values.splice($index, 1) };
});

app.directive('someDirective', () => {
  return {
  restrict: 'A',
  scope: true,
  link: (scope, element, attr, ctrls) => {
    console.log(scope.$id)
    scope.$on('$destroy', (event) => {
      console.log(scope.$id, event);
    });
  }
  } 
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.11"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    <button ng-click="add()">add</button>
    <br/>
    <div ng-repeat="value in values track by $index">
      <input some-directive ng-model="values[$index]">
      <button ng-click="remove($index)">x</button>
    <div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is the item triggered for removal indeed being removed?  As much NG stuff as I have done, I've never really used their $id simply because I've usually had other identifying data points to utilize.

Comment: Yes. You can check my snippet, enter values to inputs and you will see that correct one is being removed.

Comment: This is desired as you set `track by $index`. Ng-repeat watch you collection and as it changes, updates DOM. Imagine this change:
 [1, 2, 3, 4] -> [2, 3, 4]
You think that you removed first element, but Ng-repeat thinks that you just removed last element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @PetrAveryanov pointed out in his comment, the `track by $index` is what's causing you to see the odd behavior.  I have modified your example to show that if you remove this, you will see the proper ID is removed.  As stated in my previous comments, you should probably avoid using Angular's `$id`, using something more specific to your data structure to track.

The reason WHY this happens is if you think about your list, the UI just renders them in sequence.  With no tracking statement, it will basically create/destroy them as the list changes.  If you use the statement `track by <whatever>`, you are telling Angular to "recycle" the UI, so it gets reused rather than the DOM getting created and destroyed.  It's kind of confusing at first but this helps in rendering efficiency.

```js
/*
  bug description:
  click add button add two items,
  then remove first item
  (wrong scope is refered in scope $on destroy function)
*/

var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.values = [];
  
  $scope.add = () => { $scope.values.push(parseInt(Math.random()*100)); };
  $scope.remove = ($index) => { $scope.values.splice($index, 1) };
});

app.directive('someDirective', () => {
  return {
  restrict: 'A',
  scope: true,
  link: (scope, element, attr, ctrls) => {
if (console.clear) console.clear();
    console.log(scope.$id, 'added')
    scope.$on('$destroy', (event) => {
            
            if (console.clear) console.clear();
      console.log(scope.$id, 'removed');
    });
  }
  } 
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.11"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    <button ng-click="add()">add</button>
    <br/>
    <div some-directive ng-repeat="value in values">
      {{$id}}::{{value}}
      <button ng-click="remove($index)">x</button>
    <div>
  </body>

</html>
```